# Multiple entries with same key: ts=TypeScript and ts=TS SonarQube

Tags: typescript, sonarqube

"Edited question!"

I cannot see my project in Sonarqube. Here is a part of the log which shown the error:

**

**ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVv9QL7JYbK6uNdsszyd java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: ts=TypeScript and ts=TS    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:150) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]   at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.checkNoConflictInBucket(RegularImmutableMap.java:104) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]     at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableMap.(RegularImmutableMap.java:70) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]   at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap$Builder.build(ImmutableMap.java:254) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]     at com.google.common.collect.Maps.uniqueIndex(Maps.java:1166) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]  at com.google.common.collect.Maps.uniqueIndex(Maps.java:1140) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]  at org.sonar.server.computation.language.LanguageRepositoryImpl.(LanguageRepositoryImpl.java:46) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_74]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_74]   at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]  at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]  at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]     at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]   at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]  at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]  at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:272) ~[sonar-core-5.6.6.jar:na]    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.AbstractComputationSteps$1.apply(AbstractComputationSteps.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.AbstractComputationSteps$1.apply(AbstractComputationSteps.java:40) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]    at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:794) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]     at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]     at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]     at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]  at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75) ~[sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]  at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]   at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.6.6.jar:na]   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_74]   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_74]    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_74]   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_74]  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_74]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_74]    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_74]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]
2017.05.12 16:22:14 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=carpool | type=REPORT | id=AVv9QL7JYbK6uNdsszyd | submitter=admin | time=1688ms**

**
This was extracted from the background task page of sonar!

PlugIns:

- backelite-sonar-swift-plugin-0.3.2
- sonar-android-plugin-1.1
- sonar-csharp-plugin-5.8.0.660
- sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.4
- sonar-java-plugin-4.6.0.8784
- sonar-ldap-plugin-2.1.0.507
- sonar-php-plugin-2.9.2.1744
- sonar-python-plugin-1.7.0.1195
- sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2
- sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.4.0.522
- sonar-typescript-plugin-1.1.0
- sonar-web-frontend-plugin-2.1.0
- sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1

This file is inside plugins directory too: sonar-javascript-plugin-2.21.0.4409.jar_bak

Any idea ???

Comment: What plugins do you have enabled in SonarQube?

Comment: GIT, LDAP, SII web frontend plugin :: JS/CSS/HTML/SCSS, SVN, Sonar Java, Sonar PHP, Sonar Python, Sonar XML, Swift (Backelite) and TypeScript

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a list of plugins installed on the server, and perhaps to include a little more of the error if it seems relevant

Comment: As the error is about TypeScript, could you please try to remove the sonar-typescript-plugin and try again ?

Comment: Same problem!! nothing changed. Is there any command to avoid the sonar load all plugins and just load the necessary(ies) one?? Just for check one of them is causing the conflict. Thanks!